# mysqli prepared statements - auto trim

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Is there any way to automatically trim data when inserting it into database when using mysqli prepared statements in PHP?

Sure, I could auto apply trim() to each variable submitted via $_POST, but if any submitted element is an array, trim causes problems, so my goal is to auto apply trim() only to variables that are added to the database.

Comment: MySQL also has `TRIM()` which can be used into your `INSERT` statements. More here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Comment: If you want to always do this maybe look at mysql triggers.

Comment: Thanks Chris, so far it sounds like the best idea

Answer (score 1):

**NO, prepared statements are essentially irrelevant to whatever data modifications.**

Prepared statement is just a method for adding a data to the query. And the only its purpose is adding the data **as is,** without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) like:

```
array_walk_recursive($_POST, function ($value) {
    return is_string($value) ? trim($value) : $value;
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know this method, just thought there might be an easier way